# Run command including quotes with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to run [this command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96227) on a remote host with Ansible (version (3.6.5):

```
DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE='File /tmp/config.dat' dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config
```

I tried by including this task in my playbook:

```
- name: dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
  command: DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE='File /tmp/config.dat' dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config
```

This leads to the following error message:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "'DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE=File
>   /tmp/config.dat' dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config",
>   "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

It looks to me as if Ansible's `command` module places additional surrounding quotes, which seem to disturb mine.

So how can I run this command with Ansible? I have tried both single and double  quotes as well as escaping characters (with `\'`, `\"`, or `\`) but to no avail so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom command, you should use `shell` instead of `command`:

```
- name: dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
    shell: DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE='File /tmp/config.dat' dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config
```

Comment: `DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE='File /tmp/config.dat'` is set value for DEBCONF_DB_OVERRIDE variable, then run command  `dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config`